# Cakephp using model wtihout defining model file

Tags: php, cakephp, model

I am new to cakephp and trying to customise a cake application.

I have seen they are using models without  having model class files in app/models folder

I think there is an automatic mapping from table to model

I am sharing some usefull lines of codes

```
    public $uses = array('LinkEmperorCampaignDetail','Configuration','Article');

        $this->paginate = array(
            'conditions' => $condition,
            'limit' => 10
        );

        $this->set('articles', $this->paginate('Article'));
```

As you have seen its importing Article model using $uses variable, there is a table "articles" in database, But there is no file Article.php in app/models. I have deleted cache folder and disabled caching.

I have checked if it is automatic, by creating a table "test" and used this code

```
  $test=$this->test->find('all');;
  var_dump($test);exit();
```

but getting this error Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Please let me know how this is happening

Thanks,
Lajeesh

Comment: You should always mention the CakePHP version you are using

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
 $test = $this->Test->find('all');
```

Also, please, check [cakephp model and database conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions)

Answer (score 0):

### Model files are optional

Cake will [user an AppModel instance if there is no model file found](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html#understanding-models):

> CakePHP will dynamically create a model object for you if it cannot find a corresponding file in /app/Model.

As such a reference to`this->Article` will be an instance of `AppModel` as the model is declared in the `$uses` variable but a model file doesn't exist.

### That doesn't mean $this->RandomModel works

Referencing a random model, as seen in the question, will simply produce the following error:

> Call to a member function find() on a non-object

That's to be expected because the controller knows nothing about the `Test` model from the code in the question.

The optional model file handling does not mean that you can reference any model by expecting it to exist as a Controller class property. `$uses` exists for the purpose of telling the controller which models it needs to know about. If a model is only needed in specific circumstances, [loadModel](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::loadModel) exists for this purpose:

```
$this->loadModel('Test');
$stuff = $this->Test->find('all');
```